# Max file view or convert

Tags: 3ds-max

I am an illustrator and I have a MAX file that I would like to view since I need it as a reference. Is there any software or anything that I could use to open it? I don't want to buy 3ds max just for this.

Comment: you can get the free trial version of 3dMax http://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/free-trial

Comment: I didn't know about that. I think that I will get it. Still, it is strange that no other software can read this format. For 2d files, almost every softwares can read PSD files.

Comment: PSD is a very popular file format; MAX not so much. There are other more popular formats used for 3D file exchange, like OBJ.